# Desbloquear botão ao aparecer seção escondida

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um infográfico interativo em que a pessoa vai ter que ir clicando em determinado botões para abrir o conteúdo referente a esse botão, até ai tudo bem, mas eu queria que a pessoa apertasse em uma certa ordem, por exemplo o botão da seção 2 só se ativasse depois que ela clicou no botão da seção 1 e assim por diante, não quero esconder os botões quero deixa-los visível  e desativa-los até que a pessoa clique no botão da seção anterior. Vou colocar um exemplo do código.

```js
function aparecer(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none"){
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';

            console.log('funcionou');
        }else{
            console.log('não funcionou');
        }
    }
```

```html
<a href="#secao1"><img src="img.png" class="img-fluid" onclick="aparecer('secao1')"></a>
<a href="#secao2"><img src="img.png" class="img-fluid" onclick="aparecer('secao2')"></a>
<a href="#secao3"><img src="img.png" class="img-fluid" onclick="aparecer('secao3')"></a>

<div id="secao1" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque quisquam doloremque tempora dolorum facilis ea molestiae dolorem iure tempore, eos architecto eum aliquam quas officia quae natus animi provident.</p>
</div>
<div id="secao2" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, impedit dolorem soluta perferendis doloribus, odit vel vero iste itaque eos praesentium. Quisquam enim, aliquid harum eius vel a fugit rem?</p>
</div>
<div id="secao3" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero cumque ipsum impedit sed, accusantium dolorem modi quae iusto. Deserunt excepturi eaque mollitia voluptas fugiat accusantium assumenda aut perspiciatis libero provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores natus corrupti, sed velit iusto laborum obcaecati cumque dolore odit, tenetur, ullam commodi nam. Officiis omnis veritatis voluptatum ex aut in!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de uma maneira bem simples encadeando funções, a cada **clique** no elemento anterior o próximo elemento tem o seu evento de clique liberado:

```js
$(() => {
  $('a:eq(0)').on('click', () => {
    $('#secao1').fadeIn('slow')
    destrava2()
  })

  function destrava2() {
    $('a:eq(1)').on('click', () => {
      $('#secao2').fadeIn('slow')
      destrava3()
    })
  }

  function destrava3() {
    $('a:eq(2)').on('click', () => {
      $('#secao3').fadeIn('slow')
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#secao1"><img src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="190" height="100"></a>
<a href="#secao2"><img src="https://gizmodo.uol.com.br/wp-content/blogs.dir/8/files/2019/07/eclipse-solar-la-silla-eso-800x451.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="190" height="100"></a>
<a href="#secao3"><img src="https://timeline.canaltech.com.br/343084.1400/20-das-fotos-astronomicas-mais-legais-de-2019.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="190" height="100"></a>

<div id="secao1" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque quisquam doloremque tempora dolorum facilis ea molestiae dolorem iure tempore, eos architecto eum aliquam quas officia quae natus animi provident.</p>
</div>
<div id="secao2" style="display: none;">
  <p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
    dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
</div>
<div id="secao3" style="display: none;">
  <p>ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

tente usar esse parâmetro para desabilitar o clicável, salve em uma variável seu class para virar uma array exemplo

```
function aparecer(el) {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-fluid");
document.getElementById("secao1").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("secao2").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("secao3").style.display = 'none';
x[1].disabled = true;
x[2].disabled = true;
       if(el == "secao1"){
         document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
         x[1].disabled = false;
         x[2].disabled = true;
       }else if(el == "secao2"){
         document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
         x[0].disabled = true;
         x[2].disabled = false;
        }else{
           document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
           x[0].disabled = true;
           x[1].disabled = false;
         }
    }
```

teste o exemplo pois fiz aqui no serviço e não consegui testar. caso não funcione tente incluir um id e fazer por id.

Comment: Só um ponto os botões ja tem que começar inativos então coloque a variavel x com os primeiros x[1].disabled = true;
x[2].disabled = true; antes do if fora da função